# Where with multiples like

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm trying to check if an array of numbers has these numbers inside another array in MySQL using `where like`

Example ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00a4f3/1)):

My table:

| id | columnNumbers |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2,41 |
| 2 | 1,21,35 |
| 3 | 5,10,55 |

```
const numbers = [1, 41]
db.query(`select * from table where concat(",", columnNumbers, ",") like ${numbers.map(n => `"%,${n},%"`).join(' or ')}`)
```

Output:

| id | columnNumbers |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1,21,35 |

Expected output:

| id | columnNumbers |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2,41 |
| 2 | 1,21,35 |

MySQL version:

1. SQL Fiddle: 5.6
2. MySQL Workbench: 8.0.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from _table 
where FIND_IN_SET(1, columnNumbers)
   or FIND_IN_SET(41, columnNumbers)
```